# Bash time format HH:MM in 12 hour format AM/PM

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix, time

I am trying to print out the time in AM / PM format with this code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
  do
  key="$1"


  case $key in
  --AMPM| --ampm)
  while true;
  do
   #Time in AMPM format:
   echo $(date +"%r")
   sleep 1s;
   clear;
done
esac
done
```

I get this: HH:MM:SS
I want to get this: HH:MM

How can i alter the code to do so ? or why doesnt it work ?

Comment: `%r` is equivalent to `%I:%M:%S %p`, why do you think it shouldn't show seconds?

Comment: It seems like it should be obvious from that what you need to do if you just want hours, minutes, and am/pm.

Answer (score 25):

Format date output:

```
date +"%I:%M %p"
date +"%I:%M %P"
```

Where:

```
%I     hour (01..12)
%M     minute (00..59)
%p     locale's equivalent of either AM or PM; blank if not known
%P     like %p, but lower case
```

Comment: it now prints out HH:MM but not AM or PM

Comment: Then do this: `date +"%I:%M %p"`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using at least `bash` 4.2, you don't even need `date`:

```
printf '%(%I:%M %p)T\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the following line

```
echo $(date +"%r")
```

with

```
echo $(date +"%r" | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\):[0-9][0-9]/\1/')
```

Comment: What's the `echo` for? :-D Also, as others pointed out: `date +%I:%M`